# Sentinel-2 R gdal raster

Tags: r, raster, gdal

I would like to make a piece of code I have more efficient.
Right now I download `Sentinel-2` data in jp2 format via the open acceshub. The jp2 files that I download have, for some reason, a wrong extent. Right now I correct this in the following way (in which `file` is the filename of the jp2):

```
r = raster(file)
extent(r) = new_extent
writeRaster(r, file)
```

This method, however, writes the entire raster (which takes ages) whereas I only changed a minor detail.

Is there a neat way using **gdal** or the **raster** package to do this more efficiently?

If I print the raster I see:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1830, 1830, 3348900  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 60, 60  (x, y)
extent      : 499980, 609780, 6690240, 6800040  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=55 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs  +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /home/daniel/R/farmhack/x.jp2 
names       : x 
values      : 0, 65535  (min, max)
```

I do not know what this extent means.

Comment: what is the _wrong_ extent? Can you elaborate, and possibly share the console output of `r`?

Comment: The console output of the raster is class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1830, 1830, 3348900  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 60, 60  (x, y)
extent      : 499980, 609780, 6690240, 6800040  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=55 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /home/daniel/R/farmhack/x.jp2 
names       : x 
values      : 0, 65535  (min, max)
So the extent is not in wgs coordinates making it hard to crop. I do not exactly know what this extent even means.

Comment: `Sentinel-2` tiles are projected into UTM (your's is UTM 55N), which gives you the extent in meters within the projection. So the extent is not wrong, it's just not in geographic coordinates.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpfull. I will have a look in how to convert my wgs croping window to UTM than.